# Calendar dashlet

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I wonder if it's possible to add a calendar dashlet into the dashboard with the user's event. I've been looking but I have not found any solution. My Alfresco version is Enterprise 4.1.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but you'll need to code it yourself ;).

So I guess what you're Really asking is one of the following:

1. How can I develop such a solution?
   First try to develop it or ask the right questions so the community can help.
2. Where can I find a party who can develop such a solutions for
   version 4.1.2? There are a lot of parties who develop custom solutions (including us).
3. Is there a solution in the market?
   You've done your research so probably there is no openly available solution in the market.